# How to determine sysfs devpath from USB device VID and PID in Python?

Tags: python, linux, usb, sysfs

I need to locate a USB device in sysfs tree from its VID and PID in Python. What would be the most sensible approach here? Recursively scanning the directory tree is the only idea that comes to my mind. Are there any better approaches? I can't use libusb bindings, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the sysfs path for usb devices, /sys/bus/usb/devices/, and globbing for the idProduct and idVendor files

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idProduct
/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor
```

Answer (score 1):

Two years later and it's still not straight forward to make the connection from identifying a  device to the actual device.
You are right about having to scan sysfs to identify devices. There is currently no index from unique ID to a device.

Here is an example:

I have a USB → LPT port attached (Without a serial number)

I find the device(s) under /sys/class. In this case under usbmisc:

```
> ls -l /sys/class/usbmisc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 11 12:11 lp0 -> ../../devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4/1-1.3.4:1.0/usbmisc/lp0
```

To retrieve the vendor and other information about the device, walk the tree:

Go to the real path:

```
 > cd -P /sys/class/usbmisc/lp0
```

Walk down the branch a bit (to here: /sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4 ):

```
 > cd ../../../
```

Here you find the useful files:

  idVendor

  idProduct

  serial 

  busnum

  devnum

I can retrieve the device name in more then one way.:

I can use the busnum and devnum above and compose this device name: **/dev/usb/001/008**

or use information from /sys/class/usbmisc/lp0/uevent:

MAJOR=180

MINOR=0

DEVNAME=usb/lp0

Add /dev to the DEVNAME value and I get **/dev/usb/lp0**

I would have liked a simpler approach, with a unique key, a description and a link to every device. One might hope it will come in future versions of sysfs. But since it easier to work with, using the C sysfs API, the prospects are probably a long way ahead